# Cannot Reference ScrollViewer inside ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a perplexing problem. I have two identical project types in two separate solutions (both are WPF projects targeting .Net 4.5). In one of the projects, inside the xaml for a window, I can create a listview and, as I start to type "ScrollView", it shows up with Intellisense and I can reference it:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.[etc]></ListView>
```

However, in my other project, ScrollViewer does not show up as recognized when typing it. Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show more Code? and tell us what you want to do?

Comment: Maybe in one of those project you have custom control template for listview? Anyway ListView is kind of obsolete. Preffer DataGrid if possible

Comment: There seriously is no code to show. It happens even if I start creating a listview on a brand new window/view. It is for a double-column list with image tiles, basically. I need access to the events for the Scrollviewer.